# Is their a way for a user to input a word and have that word be (turn into) a #?

Tags: string, while-loop, user-input, java.util.scanner

I am trying to create program that roles 2 dice. Then the user and say Yes to role the dice again or say No to stop rolling the dice.

```
import java.util.*;
    public class Dice
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {

        Random dice1 = new Random();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        //varibles
        int die1;
        int die2;
        byte playagain=1;
        byte Yes = 1;
        byte No = 0;
        int total;
        int stop = 0;
        //Want find I way to change words into #s
        String start = Yes;
        while(stop<5 && start<Yes){
        stop+=1;
            die1=dice1.nextInt(6)+1;
            die2=dice1.nextInt(6)+1;
                total=die1 + die2;
                System. out. println("You rolled a "  + total+ ".");
        System. out. println("Do you want to play again?");
        System. out. println("Type Yes to keep playing you and No to stop.");
        /*I want people to be able to input Yes and that equal a # so I can use it in the While loop. Same with No.*/
        start=in.next();

        System. out. println("start is at " + start);

        }
        }
    }
```

I have looked throughout internet an could not find any help so that is why I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to read an int from your scanner, try using `Scanner.nextInt` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()

You can use `hasNextInt` to determine if using `nextInt` will work or not: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt()

If you already have the string and want to turn it into an int, try `Integer.parseInt` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)

In general, if you want to know if a function that does something basic exists, you should check the APIs in java.lang, java.util, java.io, etc (depending on where you think it would be)